# promise/callback hybrid function

Tags: javascript, promise, callback

Im playing arround with promises and callbacks and wonder what is the correct way to write a function that returns a promise if no callback is passed.

My result looks like this, but im not sure if this is correct (in the meaning of anti pattern)

```js
const mySuperFunction = function mySuperFunction(data, cb) {

    let wrapper = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {

            if (Math.random() >= 0.5) {
                resolve(Date.now());
            } else {
                reject(new Error("Not today..."));
            }

        }, 100);
    });


    if (cb) {

        wrapper.then((result) => {
            cb(null, result);
        }, (error) => {
            cb(error);
        });

    } else {
        return wrapper;
    }

};


mySuperFunction().then((time) => {
    console.log(time)
}).catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
});


mySuperFunction(null, (err, time) => {
    console.log(err, time)
});
```

Its simple: create a function and wrap the "work" code in a promise.
If no callback is passed to my function, i return the wrapped promise. If a calback is passed, i wrap/call it from `.then(...)` and `.catch(...)`

Is this ok, or do i miss some special cases where this dosn't work ?

Comment: Look's good. I'd move all that into a reusable function though.

Answer (score 0):

> Is this ok, or do i miss some special cases where this dosn't work ?

Your code works, but it adds unuseful overhead. A promise consumes more memory than callback and it is slower than callbacks.

I would write something like

```js
const { promisify } = require('util')

function mySuperFunctionCallback (data, cb) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    if (Math.random() >= 0.5) {
      cb(Date.now())
    } else {
      cb(new Error('Not today...'))
    }
  }, 100)
}

const mySuperFunctionAsync = promisify(mySuperFunctionCallback)

function mySuperFunction (data, cb) {
  if (cb) {
    mySuperFunctionCallback(data, cb)
  } else {
    return mySuperFunctionAsync(data)
  }
}

mySuperFunction().then((time) => {
  console.log(time)
}).catch((err) => {
  console.log(err)
})

mySuperFunction(null, (err, time) => {
  console.log(err, time)
})
```

Comment: Thank you, but thats one point i forget to mention. Why should i use a "extern" wrapper/function when i can directly include it in the function ? Your example looks like more overhead to me than my code.

Comment: I create a 2 function more than you. You are creating a promise for each callback interface call: this is a great overhead and if you don't trust me, you may misure it with a benchmark of course